# Return value from another table that matches values from the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a simple problem. I have tables A and B, both contain 3 common columns (`name, id, date`), and besides those 3, both tables have completely different set of columns.

Now, I need to relate data from Table B to table A for visualization purposes. Since I am not that good with SQL, I thought I could ask if it's possible, I know I can have computed columns as I already have one in table A for something simple. However I want to do something like this :

A new column in table A that contains a value of the column "Special" from table B for any row where name, date and ID from table A matches name, date and ID for table B, if no matches leave as blank or null.

Example

Table A:

```
Name | Date          | ID  | OtherData1     | OtherData2
-----+---------------+-----+----------------+-------------
John | March 2020    | SPC | Randomstuff    | randomstuff
Doe  | March 2020    | SPC | Randomstuff    | randomstuff
John | February 2020 | SPC | RandomStuff    | RandomStuff
Doe  | February 2020 | SPC | Randomstuff    | randomstuff
```

Table B:

```
Name | Date          | ID  | MoreData1     | SomeData2     | Special
-----+---------------+-----+---------------+---------------+--------
John | March 2020    | SPC | Randomstuff   | randomstuff   | True
Doe  | March 2020    | SPC | Randomstuff   | randomstuff   | False
John | February 2020 | SPC | RandomStuff   | RandomStuff   | True
Doe  | February 2020 | SPC | Randomstuff   | randomstuff   | True
```

Result in table A:

```
Name | Date          | ID  | OtherData1    |OtherData2   | SpecialImported
-----+---------------+-----+---------------+-------------+----------------
John | March 2020    | SPC | Randomstuff   | randomstuff | True
Doe  | March 2020    | SPC | Randomstuff   | randomstuff | False
John | February 2020 | SPC | RandomStuff   | RandomStuff | True
Doe  | February 2020 | SPC | Randomstuff   | randomstuff | True
```

Is this possible to do in SQL Server?

Comment: An alternative to denormalizing (?!) your tables is to create a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that combines the data from the two tables. You can then `select` data from the view without worrying about the underlying query.

Comment: my issue is that im pulling both tables to power bi and from them I am trying to connect them. The issue also comes where table B has a lot less data on certain report dates compared to table A, and Name sometimes is equal for different ID. so it creates an ambiguety that messes up the data visualizations.  What I want to do is make sure I pull the SpecialImported Value when name,date and id all match at the same time or else leave it null.   Thanks for your input though as I will use this to show the issue with the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But in order to reference another table in a computed column, you have to do it via creating a user-defined function. This will have name,date,id as input parameters and will output a bit if such a combination exists in table B. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_check_tableB_tuple](@name nvarchar(max),@date datetime,@ID nvarchar(max))

RETURNS bit
as
begin
declare @result bit
select @result=Special from tableB where name=@name and date=@date and ID=@ID

RETURN @result

end
```

Then, you can use this function in a computed column:

```
alter table tableA add SpecialImported as (dbo.f_check_tableB_tuple(name,date,ID))
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution I am looking, since my table A and B will usually receive new data weekly and I do not want to run a script each time to do this.  How would I create a function and record it on my sql server management application?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Just...run the query? just like you would run a SELECT.

Comment: So for the function, once I create it and run it from new query? will it be saved by sql? so if any new data comes, I do not have to run this again?

Comment: One small question, lets say table A, has a different name for a column, like in B table columns are Name,ID,Date, but on table A , its MainName,ID,Date.  I would change ina function this on the" @name "value correct, it would be "@MainName" ?

Comment: Nevermind, small slip iof mind, I understand now clearly, thank you

Comment: I want to add, doing this leaves me with a  "incorrect syntax near 'exists'"

Comment: ok, you can use instead `case when exists(...) then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: thank, this helps me understand a bit more syntax, however the problem I had was trying to return a value that is a boolean from tableB,in the column special. I believe that the function above returns a true if if name,date and report date are equal but not the value from that column.  I will keep your answer marked as I think it points me in the correct direction for a syntax like this.

Comment: Oh, there is a column named "Special" on Table B, I didn't notice that. I changed my answer, try it now.

Comment: Thank you, this  helps me.  A quick question, lets say some rows on table A will not match table B (table A has more data than table B), would they stay null?

Comment: Yes, since `select`ing into a variable for an empty result set sets it to null.

Comment: Allthough this was something nice, it is slow, my table B has 6 million rows and my table A has 8 million :) which ended up making it near infinite loading times.  My approach to sql function had a wrong assumption that this would update the table on the sql server ,and an outside query from another software would query the updated table but it seems that when I query table A, during the query it also calculates the new column which takes al ot of time, im back on the drawing board in a way to obtain that value from tableB where those 3 columns of B matches the 3 of column A .

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a `left join`:

```
select a.*, b.special special_imported
from tablea a
left join tableb b
    on a.name = b.name
    and a.date = b.date
    and a.id = b.id
```

Comment: so using this query on lets say table A, would add to table A the column special matching name,date and id correct? And would I need to run this query each time I updated table A and B ? my table A and B get updated weekly and was looking for some sort of computed column that could let me leave it like that and it would update it self as long as I updated A and B